# Adding Google Calendar event end time to script

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I have a script which lists Google Calendar events with the start time, name and description but I would like to have the end time too so it reads;

> 5:00pm - 6:00pm - Event title - event description

Rather than just what it has at the moment which is just the start time and not the end time.

This is the script I have:

```
$(document).ready(GCalEvents());

function GCalEvents() {
    var datenow = new Date();
    var curyear = datenow.getFullYear();
    var curmonth = datenow.getMonth() + 1;
    var curdate = datenow.getDate();
    var curhour = datenow.getHours();
    var curmin = datenow.getMinutes();
    var curtz = datenow.getTimezoneOffset();
    //curtz = -480;
    var plusmin = "-";
    if (curtz <= 0) {
        plusmin = "%2B";
    }
    curtz = Math.abs(curtz);
    var curtzmin = curtz % 60;
    curtz = parseInt(curtz / 60);
    if (curtzmin < 10) { curtzmin = "0" + curtzmin; }
    if (curtz < 10) { curtz = "0" + curtz; }

    datenow = curyear + "-" + curmonth + "-" + curdate + "T" + curhour + "%3A" + curmin + "%3A00" + plusmin + curtz + "%3A" + curtzmin;

    var url =  "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarid}/events?alwaysIncludeEmail=false&maxResults=2&orderBy=startTime&showDeleted=false&showHiddenInvitations=false&singleEvents=true&timeMin=" + datenow + "&fields=items(start%2Csummary%2Cdescription)%2CtimeZone&key={key}";
//    var url =  "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarid}/events?alwaysIncludeEmail=false&maxResults=2&orderBy=startTime&showDeleted=false&showHiddenInvitations=false&singleEvents=true&timeMin=" + datenow + "&fields=items(start%2Csummary%2Cdescription)%2CtimeZone&key={key}";

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var event_start_date_new = new Date();
    event_start_date_new.setDate(event_start_date_new.getDate() - 1);

    for(i in data['items']) {
            item = data['items'][i];

        // event title
            var event_title = item.summary;
            var event_description = item.description;

        // event start date/time
            var event_start_date = new Date(item.start.dateTime);

        // format the date and time
            var month = event_start_date.getMonth();
            var day = event_start_date.getDay();
            var date = event_start_date.getDate();

            var daysArr = new Array();
            daysArr[0] = "Sunday";
            daysArr[1] = "Monday";
            daysArr[2] = "Tuesday";
            daysArr[3] = "Wednesday";
            daysArr[4] = "Thursday";
            daysArr[5] = "Friday";
            daysArr[6] = "Saturday";

            var monthsArr = new Array();
            monthsArr[0] = "January";
            monthsArr[1] = "February";
            monthsArr[2] = "March";
            monthsArr[3] = "April";
            monthsArr[4] = "May";
            monthsArr[5] = "June";
            monthsArr[6] = "July";
            monthsArr[7] = "August";
            monthsArr[8] = "September";
            monthsArr[9] = "October";
            monthsArr[10] = "November";
            monthsArr[11] = "December";

            var hour = event_start_date.getHours();
            var min = event_start_date.getMinutes();
            if (min < 10) { min = "0" + min; }
            if (hour < 11) {
        var ampm = "am";
        if (hour == 0) { hour = 12; }
            } else {
        var ampm = "pm";
        if (hour > 12) { hour = hour - 12; }
            }
            if (hour < 10) { hour = "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + hour; }

            var event_start_str = daysArr[day] + ", " + monthsArr[month] + " " + date;
            var event_time_str = hour + ":" + min + " " + ampm;

            if (event_start_date.getDate() != event_start_date_new.getDate()) {
        event_start_str = "<div class=\"calendar_date\"><strong>" + event_start_str + "</strong></div>";
        event_start_date_new = event_start_date;
            } else {
        event_start_str = "";
            };



            // Render the event
            $("#gcal-events").last().before("<div class=\"calendar_item\"><li>" + event_time_str + "&nbsp;-&nbsp;" + event_title + "<p><small>" + event_description + "</small></p></ul>" + "</li></div>");
    }
    });
};
```

If anyone is able to help with that to reversion the current script, that would be great.

Comment: Have you looked at what properties are returned for each event? Do you have like a start date and a duration? What does the calendar Api return to you

Answer (score 0):

The [Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) resource returns `start` and `end` dates as well (JSON format that has `date`, `dateTime`, `timeZone` attributes).

Based on your code, you're not using the `end` attribute which is why you're not having any values for the end date displayed. Your code for the start date is alright, so you can just re-implement it for the `end` attribute.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Any idea how to implement this into the current script @adjuremods?